# Select only rows where an attribute changes

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

There is 1 table wherein all these records are maintained for 1 employee. Due to one more column in this table which is not shown in this example the person has multiple rows for even 1 job , i.e. 2 rows for job J1 , 3 for Job J2 and again 2 rows for job J1 in order and same way for location. The person switches from job J1 to J2 and then again J1 and same way changes happens for location .How to extract the required rows whenever a switch happens as I have to extract the max of each row when job or location is changed.  Please help me.

```
StDt             EdDt           Job      Location Required_Rows
01-Jan-21      31-Jan-21        J1         L1          N
01-Feb-21      30-Jun-21        J1         L1          Y
01-Jul-21      30-Jul-21        J2         L1          Y
01-Aug-21      15-Aug-21        J2         L2          N 
16-Aug-21      31-Aug-21        J2         L2          Y
01-Sep-21      01-Nov-21        J1         L2          Y
02-Nov-21      31-Dec-21        J1         L1          Y
```

Post this change I also need to add changes from another table which I will join from location present in the above table to this location table and need to capture changes within same location.
Ex:

```
StDt             EdDt           Job      Location      (Column in Loc Table : Status)        Required_Rows
01-Jan-21      15-Jan-21        J1         L1                    A                             Y
16-Jan-21      31-Jan-21        J1         L1                    B                             N
01-Feb-21      30-Jun-21        J1         L1                    B                             Y
01-Jul-21      30-Jul-21        J2         L1                    B                             Y
01-Aug-21      15-Aug-21        J2         L2                    B                             N 
16-Aug-21      31-Aug-21        J2         L2                    B                             Y
01-Sep-21      01-Nov-21        J1         L2                    B                             Y
02-Nov-21      31-Dec-21        J1         L1                    B                             Y
```

EDIT :(Post this change I also need to add changes from another table which I will join from location present in the above table to this location table and need to capture changes within same location.)

Plz revert answer for this second table how do I pull the data in 1 query for changes within same location which is the master table of location.

Hey Guys,

The second table looks like this:

```
 StDt             EdDt        Status       Location 

01-Jan-21      15-Jan-21        A          L1  
   
16-Jan-21      31-Dec-21        B          L1  
   
01-Jan-21      31-Dec-21        B          L2
```

Comment: Please, describe how `2021-01-15` appeared in the output? There is no such a date in sample data

Comment: Hey that is not the output... those are two different data sets... Required_Rows column tells what should be thw rows in the output , the ones which are Y.... I need a solution for both the data sets.

Comment: Then what should be the output for this sample data?

Comment: The rows which have Required_Rows column as Y that should be the output of the data with all the columns.

Comment: So I have given 2 data sets as I need solution to both the data sets... within those data sets only I have specified which rows I need in those data sets as my output by specifying Required_Rows columns as Y. The rows having Required_Rows as N is not required in output .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY stDt
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ({- same* -} same )
  DEFINE
    same AS FIRST(job) = job AND FIRST(location) = location
)
```

and for earlier versions, you can use the `LEAD` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT StDt,
       EdDt,
       Job,
       location
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD(job) OVER (ORDER BY StDt) AS next_job,
         LEAD(location) OVER (ORDER BY StDt) AS next_location
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  next_job IS NULL
OR     next_job != job
OR     next_location IS NULL
OR     next_location != location;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (StDt, EdDt, Job, Location) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-31', 'J1', 'L1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-01', DATE '2021-06-30', 'J1', 'L1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-01', DATE '2021-07-31', 'J2', 'L1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-15', 'J2', 'L2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-08-16', DATE '2021-08-31', 'J2', 'L2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-09-01', DATE '2021-11-01', 'J1', 'L2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-11-01', DATE '2021-12-31', 'J1', 'L1' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> | STDT | EDDT | JOB | LOCATION |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | J1 | L1 |
> | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-31 00:00:00 | J2 | L1 |
> | 2021-08-16 00:00:00 | 2021-08-31 00:00:00 | J2 | L2 |
> | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | J1 | L2 |
> | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | J1 | L1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b559943ed4798b8cb6a44c67e0e7525b)*

---

> Post this change I also need to add changes from another table which I will join from location_id present in the above table to this location table and need to capture changes within 1 location.

There is not enough information on the structure of the other table or how the two tables would be joined to be able to answer this part of the question.

Comment: Hey, I have added the data of the second table, how it will look like. Please help. Thanks for your revert. I am using lead function.